# Adding floats precision

Tags: python, floating-point

First time encountering floating point arithmetic.

How can I add:

```
0.4047617913405519 + 250459325658972.0
```

and choose my presicion?

I get

```
250459325658972.4
```

But I want at least

```
250459325658972.405
```

Why is python doing that. Any further resources?

Comment: Python `float`s only have about 15 decimal digits of precision.  what you're trying to do would require 18, so it's getting rounded to the nearest value it can represent.  see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format if you want to see the actual representation or https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html for python specific info

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is the [Decimal module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html):

```py
>>> from decimal import *
>>> getcontext().prec = 6
>>> Decimal(1) / Decimal(7)
Decimal('0.142857')
>>> getcontext().prec = 28
>>> Decimal(1) / Decimal(7)
Decimal('0.1428571428571428571428571429')
```

It gives complete control on the precision of your operations as long as you use `Decimal` objects.

Answer (score -3):

Use this

```
print("{0:.4f}".format(250459325658972.0 +0.4047617913405519))
```

Comment: there isn't enough precision in a Python `float` to represent the result of this calculation accurately.  e.g. try `250459325658972.0 +0.41` and you'll get the same output

Comment: This prints 250459325658972.4062, not 250459325658972.404 or 250459325658972.405.  Do you know why?